# I have this loop that provides me the 'markup' amount for a series of transactions I need to print the total

Tags: python

This code on its own gives me each amount I need. The trick is to get it to print or I could append it as a new column and then total it. I've attempted a number of ways to including setting as defined function (syntax error) and printing the total (unexpected arg).

```py
for key,value in df.cost_of_the_order.iteritems():
    if value >= 20:
        print(value*.25)
    elif value <=19.99:
        print(value*.15)
    elif value > 5:
        print(value*0)  
        break
```

Comment: Your last elif will never run because if the value is greater than 5, its either less than/equal to 19.99 or greater than/equal to 20 (I guess it hypothetically could if the value was, say 19.999). To get a total, just define `total=0` before the loop. In each if statement, include `total +=value*markup` and then after the loop is finished, `print(total)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to make markup a different way, but it worked like a charm. I'm going to add my code below.

Answer (score 1):

```
# set new var for the totals of each surcharge and run loops on each with conditions to create totals

total = 0
markup1 = .250
markup2 = .15

for key,value in df.cost_of_the_order.iteritems():
    if value >= 20:
        total +=value*markup1
        
    elif value <=19.99:
        total +=value*markup2
       
    elif value < 5:
        total +=value*0
          
print(total)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).